# odd lambda behavior

Tags: c#, lambda, closures

I stumbled across [this article](http://www.float4x4.net/index.php/2011/05/loops-and-lambdas) and found it very interesting, so I ran some tests on my own:

**Test One:**

```
List<Action> actions = new List<Action>();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    actions.Add(() => Console.WriteLine(i));

foreach (Action action in actions)
    action();
```

Outputs:

```
5
5
5
5
5
```

---

**Test Two:**

```
List<Action> actions = new List<Action>();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    int j = i;
    actions.Add(() => Console.WriteLine(j));
}

foreach (Action action in actions)
    action();
```

Outputs:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

---

According to the article, in Test One all of the lambdas contain a reference to `i` which causes them to all output 5.  Does that mean I get the *expected* results in Test Two because a new `int` is created for each lambda expression?

Comment: Yes ...because you are assigning `i` to `j` within each iteration, a new reference to `j` is captured by the lambda - and the results in the 2nd test are as expected. I don't have Jon Skeet's *C# in Depth* handy, so I can't reference his information on capturing variables in lambdas. I seem to recall he does go into some detail on capturing values in lambdas.

Comment: If you have a background in C/C++, think of it as passing the memory address rather than the value itself. So, you're passing &i - and at the end of the loop i == 5. j is created inside the scope, so its value is not modified afterwards.

Comment: This question has been asked so many times...

Comment: This question is asked a couple times every day in the context of JavaScript by programmers who haven't been properly introduced to closures and variable capturing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because of **[variable capturing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matt/archive/2008/03/01/understanding-variable-capturing-in-c.aspx)** in C# that can be a little tricky

In a nutshell, Each loop of the for loop is referring to the same variable **i** so the compiler uses the same lambda expression for all loops.

If it is any consolation, This **oddity** is worse in javascript as javascript only has function scopes for variables so even your second solution won't do what you expect it to.

[This is also a very good explanation](http://www.ikriv.com/en/prog/info/dotnet/lambdas.html)

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a `problem`, rather, a feature. Albeit an unintuitive feature when you first run into it

Answer (score 7):

@Eric Lippert has explained this in great detail in his two-parts article:

- [Closing over the loop variable considered harmful](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx)
- [Closing over the loop variable, part two](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/16/closing-over-the-loop-variable-part-two.aspx)

It is a must-read article, as it explains the behavior in depth and at implementation-level.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

In Test One the var `i` is captured in the loop, but `i` refers to a variable that is effectively declared **once outside** the loop, so all of the captured lambdas refer to the **one variable**. By the time you call the actions the value of `i` is `5` so all of the output is five.

In Test Two the var `j` is captured in the loop, but in this case `j` is declared **each time inside** the loop, so all of the captured lambdas refer to the **distinct variables**. So calling the lambdas outputs the distinct values.