# .NET6 strange for loop bug

Tags: c#, for-loop, .net-6.0

After writing a code with threads inside "for" loop, somehow the incremented value continues after the statement is false. I even try to double check it... How is that even possible?

[for loop strange bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iv2rD.png)

Comment: Please post code, not screenshots of code. But I can tell you this is nothing to do with .NET6

Comment: The bug is in your code, not in .NET. Basically the *variable* `i` is captured, not the value in the loop. I'll find a duplicate...

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116709 (and many others)

Comment: Many many others, like [Why is it bad to use an iteration variable in a lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227820/why-is-it-bad-to-use-an-iteration-variable-in-a-lambda-expression) and [Captured variable in a loop in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/captured-variable-in-a-loop-in-c-sharp)